# Where clause not working in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My Stored procedure is like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE     Proc_SearchRequests
(
RequestedBy LONG,
FromDate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
ToDate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
RequestedByDesignation VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
TypeId INT,
CurrentStatusId INT DEFAULT NULL, 
AmountFrom LONG DEFAULT NULL,
AmountTo LONG DEFAULT NULL,
cur_ExcelOutput OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
AS   
BEGIN
OPEN cur_ExcelOutput FOR
SELECT cd.*,
emp.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || emp.LASTNAME   AS ADDEDBYNAME
FROM 
DETAILS cd
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES emp ON cd.ADDEDBY = emp.EMPLOYEEID
WHERE
cd.TYPEID=TypeId;   

END;
```

I am passing executing procedure as:

```
BEGIN
PROC_SEARCHREQUESTS (110, to_date ('2001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date ('9999-12-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), null, 2, 0, 0, 0, :cur_exceloutput$REFCURSOR);
END;
```

But whatever I pass as TypeId I get complete data and not the filtered one..
If i write "cd.TYPEID=2" I get proper result but passing value in varible is not helping.

What can be wrong?.. Am I missing any casting or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have name collision. The variable has the same name as column. 
Change the variable(parameter)

```
TypeId INT,
```

into

```
p_TypeId INT,
```

Comment: This actually worked...But I did not understood the reason...What is with this "p_"?

Comment: Ok I got it..I did not know that Variable name can not be same as Column name.. Thanks..this added to my knowledge..

Comment: p comes from parameter. Is a naming convention. I just changed the name of your variable.

Answer (score 4):

When you're writing a stored procedure, you always want to have some sort of naming convention to differentiate local variables, procedure parameters, and database columns.  Since identifiers are first resolved using the name of a column in the table and then using the name of a local variable or parameter, both sides of the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE cd.TYPEID=TypeId;
```

resolves to the `TypeID` column of the `Details` table.  This query won't ever look at the value in the parameter `TypeID`.

If you adopt a standard naming convention (i.e. prefixing parameters with `p_` and local variables with `l_`), you won't have to worry about introducing scope resolution bugs.

Something like this should work (though the data types you're using are pretty unusual-- `LONG`, for example, has been deprecated for a long time so you should really be using a `VARCHAR2` there (or a `CLOB` if you really need more than 32k which seems unlikely given the names)).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE     Proc_SearchRequests
(
  p_RequestedBy LONG,
  p_FromDate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  p_ToDate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  p_RequestedByDesignation VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  p_TypeId INT,
  p_CurrentStatusId INT DEFAULT NULL, 
  p_AmountFrom LONG DEFAULT NULL,
  p_AmountTo LONG DEFAULT NULL,
  p_cur_ExcelOutput OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS   
BEGIN
  OPEN p_cur_ExcelOutput FOR
    SELECT cd.*,
           emp.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || emp.LASTNAME   AS ADDEDBYNAME
    FROM 
      DETAILS cd
      LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES emp ON cd.ADDEDBY = emp.EMPLOYEEID
    WHERE
      cd.TYPEID=p_TypeId;   
END;
```